# How to inject a generic IList<> of objects using Unity 2 XML config?

Tags: unity-container

I need to inject a collection of type `IList<IActivity>` into a constructor. I am using Unity 2.0 and configuring it using XML.

I was able to do this by just injecting an array in Unity 1.2. I have just upgraded to Unity 2.0 and my configuration has now stopped working in this specific area. (I have resolved all the trivial changes to the schema.)

My constructor looks like this:

```
public DoSomethingWorkflow(IList<IActivity> activityCollection)
{
  ...
}
```

My config looks like this:

```
<alias alias="IListOfIActivity" type="System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[MyProject.IActivity, MyProject]], mscorlib"/>

<alias alias="IActivityArray" type="MyProject.IActivity[], MyProject" />

<register type="IWorkflow" mapTo="Workflow" name="DoSomethingWorkflow">
    <constructor>
      <param name="activityCollection" type="IListOfIActivity">
        <array>
          <dependency name="DoSomethingActivity1"/>
          <dependency name="DoSomethingActivity2"/>
        </array>
      </param>
    </constructor>     
</register>
```

If I run the config as above I get an error message saying "*The configuration is set to inject an array, but the type IList`1 is not an array type*".

If I change it to the way it used to work (injecting the type alias IActivityArray) I get an error message saying "*Configuration is incorrect, the type MyProject.Workflow does not have a constructor that takes parameters named activityCollection*".

If I remove the type attribute from the constructor element completely, I get the same error message as above.

The only way I can get this to work is to change the constructor to accept an IActivity[] array instead.

So is this a bug in Unity, as an array is an IList and should find the constructor? Or am I missing something in my config?

Comment: Great, I just got a Tumbleweed badge for this one! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can try to apply an alias instead of inheriting to a new type.

```
using  ActivityList=System.Collections.Generic.List<IActivity>;
//.... after some declarations
var activityList = new ActivityList();
```

I've been reading about Unity configuration file. I know you can create alias, but I'm not sure how to specify generics

BTW This article has an explanation an options to use generics ;-)
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/A-First-Look-at-Unity-2-0.aspx
I hope this helps

**EDIT**:

After taking some time trying to use it, here is my answer:
List Suppose you want to use resolve from "IList" to "List".

**1** First you will have to prepare your configuration file, in this case it's using signed references to IList as well as List.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="StringListContract" type="System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <alias alias="ConcreteStringList" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <container>
      <register type="StringListContract" mapTo="ConcreteStringList">
        <lifetime type="ContainerControlledLifetimeManager" />
        <constructor />
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

**2** 
Use the container to resolve the dependency ;-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
namespace UnityTerminal
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.LoadConfiguration();
            {
                var concreteStringList = container.Resolve<System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.String>>();
                concreteStringList.Add("Hello World");
            }
            {
                var concreteStringList = container.Resolve<System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.String>>();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", concreteStringList[0]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

That should be enough, I hope this works ;-)
Best regards,
Herber

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a type ActivityList that derives from `IList<IActivity>`.

```
class ActivityList : IList<IActivity>
{ /* */ }
```

This kind of stuff inside a config file:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[MyProject.IActivity, MyProject]], mscorlib
```

is hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: The format of `1[[MyProject.IActivity, MyProject]] was very difficult to find. Thanks for posting this! I agree, though, that it is difficult to maintain, but in some cases there is no alternative :-(